# Git hook to disallow directory creation in top level

Tags: git, access-control, githooks

Any better way to prevent stop top level directory creation by users may be while on push or direct file creation?

Answer (score 2):

This answer supplements [VonC answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332416/git-hook-to-disallow-directory-creation-in-top-level/3332478#3332478).

---

As each developer should have his/her own clone (his/her own working repository), the only control you can realistically impose<sup>1</sup> is on allowing or disallowing during push to publish repository (or during you pulling their changes).  This can be done using `update` or `pre-receive` [hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).

<sup>1) The `pre-commit` hook can be bypassed with "git commit --no-verify"</sup>

I don't know if any ready solution support constraint you want to impose, but I think that both [update-paranoid](http://repo.or.cz/w/git.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/contrib/hooks/update-paranoid) example hook (from `contrib/hooks` in git sources), and [gitolite](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) (the tool to manage access to git repositories) can be extended to support it; both can do path based / diff based constraints, for example allow changes only to given configured subdirectory.

Comment: Excellent addition. +1. Since I just have installed a gitolite, I will have a look and see how it could support such a constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a [client-side hook](http://progit.org/book/ch7-3.html), like a

> The `pre-commit` hook is run first, before you even type in a commit message.
>   It’s used to inspect the snapshot that’s about to be committed, to see if you’ve forgotten something, to make sure tests run, or to examine whatever you need to inspect in the code.  Exiting non-zero from this hook aborts the commit, although you can bypass it with `git commit --no-verify`.

See [this example of advance pre-commit hook](http://github.com/jwiegley/git-scripts/blob/47a743a7aa519d6d677d800742e4db47570e1bc6/pre-commit.sh) to see what it is possible to do in term of checking the index content.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want that level of control over what goes into the master repository, don't let other people push to it.  Instead, have the manager pull from other users and review their changes to make sure they haven't violated policies.